# Does ReportPortal have an API to create/edit Dashboards and Dashboard widgets?

Tags: dashboard, reportportal

We have many different configurations in our test runs and would like to have ReportPortal Dashboards for each.  They would all be very similar but for one or two filter value changes.  Creating them via the UI is tedious.  Is there some way we could automate this process via API?

My initial searches in the documentation on the website didn't hit anything.  I will be diving into GitHub to see what is there - but if someone knows current and/or future plans for such a thing (or something else that would help, I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

My documentation searches were in github and the website.  Once I found the Swagger API documentation inside the app (log in and click on the icon at the bottom of the strip down the left), I found what I need, the dashboard-controller.